# Why does NMSLIB scale badly when I insert a CSR Matrix in a cosinesimil HNSW Index?

Tags: python, vectorization, sparse-matrix, knn, nmslib

I'm working with text embeddings, stored in a sparse format as a `csr_matrix` (generated via a *TfIdfVectorizer*). I'd like to use NMSLIB's [cosinesimil/HNSW index](https://nmslib.github.io/nmslib/quickstart.html#example-usage) to insert them and do a Nearest Neighbors search.

My problem is that inserting the `embeddings.toarray()` doesn't scale when I have more than e.g. 1M embeddings to insert. I noticed [here](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib/issues/480#issuecomment-849523154) that inserting directly a csr_matrix without calling `toarray()` seems supported:

```py
test_features = sparse.csr_matrix(test_features)
train_features = sparse.csr_matrix(train_features)

nsw = nmslib.init(method = 'sw-graph', space = 'cosinesimil_sparse', data_type=nmslib.DataType.SPARSE_VECTOR)
nsw.addDataPointBatch(train_features)
```

However, when I try inserting my embeddings, I get this error:

```py
    self.similar_items_index = nmslib.init(space='cosinesimil', method='hnsw')
    self.similar_items_index.addDataPointBatch(self.embeddings)
```

->

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pln/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/213.7172.26/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/pln/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/213.7172.26/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/pln/Work/project/foo/bar/baz.py", line 140, in <module>
    cbf_model.train()
  File "/home/pln/Work/project/foo/bar/baz.py", line 152, in timing_wrapper
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pln/Work/project/foo/bar/baz.py", line 130, in train
    self.insert_datapoints()
  File "/home/pln/Work/project/foo/bar/baz.py", line 152, in timing_wrapper
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pln/Work/project/foo/bar/baz.py", line 159, in insert_datapoints
    self.similar_items_index.addDataPointBatch(self.embeddings)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
python-builtins.ValueError
```

Is this expected, or should I be able to insert a *csr_matrix* as-is to such an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the *space* used: as you can see in the quoted example, the proper way to insert a [Compressed Sparse Row Matrix](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csr_matrix.html) is to use the **`cosinesimil_sparse`** space.

See [NMSLIB's documentation for spaces](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib/blob/master/manual/spaces.md#input-format), in particular the section on Input Format:

> For **sparse spaces** that include the Lp-spaces, the sparse cosine similarity, and the maximum-inner product space, the **input data is a sparse scipy matrix**. An example can be found here.